# Quality checker for PDF to Word conversion process

Tags: desktop-application

I am doing a PDF to Word conversion process. I need a quality checker which generates a error report for my PDF to Word converted files. I am using [ABBYY](http://www.abbyy.com/) software for my conversion process. Can you please suggest the best quality checker?

I am doing a non-voice process (PDF to MS word conversion process).  We all know that checking this output with PDF is a quite time consuming task. I came to know that there is an automatic checker which checks the contents in the PDF and Word and generates an error report for the converted work done. If you need further information, please visit  [thebinarycomputer.com/SpellCheck.html](http://thebinarycomputer.com/SpellCheck.html). The software at that link is not effective; I need better software than this.

Khallas Spell-checking Software

OVERVIEW

This Software is able to compare between Image (PDF / JPG / TIF or Other Type) file & Word file. It can compare more than one file at a time. It is not necessary to check your Word file manually with Image file at the time of converting Image file into Word file using any OCR technology. Our software can detect error from word file as per your image file. And also it is able to do Auto Correction. This is fully automatic in nature. At the same time it shows original Image file, original Word file along with zoomed Image Highlighted portion. This shows error with different color at the time of compare between Image file and Word file. Accordingly, we can take decision easily.

ADVANTAGES

```
* Ensure Your Accuracy level
* Save Your Time
* Save Your Labor
* Save Your Money
* Less Your Tension
* Enjoy With Your Family Member
```

FEATURE

```
* Word File will be compared with Image File.
* Word File’s content will be 100% same as per Image File.
* Automatic update is possible.
* In Table, content will be checked Cell by Cell.
* Able to remove automatically any junk character.
* If you miss any character, word, line, and paragraph, or if any word written twice, it will be detected and autocorrected.
* It can check Single Line Equation or Multi Line Equation (A-Z / 0-9) but it can not check any Scientific Equation or Scientific Character, just show it as error.
* Automatically Detect Error: Case error, Bold error, Italics error, Comma [,], Full stop [.], Semicolon [;], Colon [:], Optional hyphen [-], Super script, Sub script and any Special Character.
```

Comment: As i am doing a Non voice process (pdf to MS word convertion process).we all know that checking this output with pdf s a quite time consuming task. I came to know tat ther s a automatic checker which checks the contents in the pdf and word and generates a error report to the converted work done.
If u need furthe information plz visit this link http://www.thebinarycomputer.com/SpellCheck.html

The software in that link s not effective.i need a better software link this

Comment: What do you mean by "quality"? How well the document structure was preserved?

Comment: Maybe quality is only about text content? The content and order of apperance must be preserved?

Comment: In what way is this a programming question?

Comment: yes sir plz check tat link tat i have mentioned in my question .. i need such a similar software

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by "quality check" in your question...What are you checking for?

Comment: http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Search/spell_check.html http://www.spellcheckanywhere.com/ http://spellex.com/ http://www.spellchecker.com/

Comment: this s not the one i am looking for my friend but any way really thanks a lot for ur care in answering me..

Comment: i dont think that ther s no software like this in the market.. So all developers check this out If u develop such a software sucessfullly and reliably
the features of the software s as follows